# Decipher iPhone crashlog

Tags: ios, debugging, crash-log

I got a crash for my own app on my iPhone, and am trying to figure out what happened. Here is the relevant part from the crash log in Xcode (sorry for the poor formatting):

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>     0x1828c2d8c **exceptionPreprocess + 228 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x181a7c5ec objc_exception_throw + 55 2   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x1828d0098 -[NSObject+ 1388696 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
>   + 139 3   CoreFoundation                  0x1828c85c8 ___forwarding_** + 1379 4   CoreFoundation                  0x1827ae41c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 91 5   MyApp                        0x102c33a0c 0x102bf0000 + 277004 6   MyApp
>   0x102c39d9c 0x102bf0000 + 302492 7   MyApp
>   0x102c1bed8 0x102bf0000 + 179928 8   MyApp
>   0x102c0754c 0x102bf0000 + 95564 9   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x1821b4aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23 10 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x1821b4a60 _dispatch_client_callout +
>   15 11  libdispatch.dylib              0x1821f5bcc
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 527 12  CoreFoundation                 0x18286b070
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 11 13  CoreFoundation                    0x182868bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2271 14 
>   CoreFoundation                    0x182788da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 551
>   15  GraphicsServices                  0x18476e020 GSEventRunModal + 99 16
>   UIKit                             0x18c7a8758 UIApplicationMain + 235 17 
>   MyApp                         0x102bf48f4 0x102bf0000 + 18676 18 
>   libdyld.dylib                     0x182219fc0 start + 3
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00000001823492e0
>   **pthread_kill + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001824ee6a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360 2
>
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00000001822b7d0c abort + 140 3
>
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x0000000181a532c8 __cxa_bad_cast + 0 4
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x0000000181a53470
>   default_unexpected_handler+ 5232 () + 0 5   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x0000000181a7c8d4 _objc_terminate+ 35028 () + 124 6
>
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x0000000181a6d37c
>   std::__terminate(void (*)+ 111484 ()) + 16 7   libc++abi.dylib
>
>     0x0000000181a6cccc __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func+ 109772
>   (_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0 8   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x0000000181a7c720 _objc_exception_destructor+ 34592 (void*) + 0 9
>
>   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001828d0098
>   __methodDescriptionForSelector + 0 10  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001828c85c8 ___forwarding_** + 1380 11  CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001827ae41c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92 12  MyApp
>         0x0000000102c33a0c 0x102bf0000 + 277004 13  MyApp                           0x0000000102c39d9c 0x102bf0000 + 302492 14  MyApp                           0x0000000102c1bed8 0x102bf0000 + 179928 15  MyApp                           0x0000000102c0754c 0x102bf0000 + 95564 16  libdispatch.dylib                0x00000001821b4aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 17 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001821b4a60
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821f5bcc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 +
>   528 19  CoreFoundation                    0x000000018286b070
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12 20  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182868bc8 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   2272 21  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000182788da8
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 22  GraphicsServices
>     0x000000018476e020 GSEventRunModal + 100 23  UIKit
>     0x000000018c7a8758 UIApplicationMain + 236 24  MyApp
>         0x0000000102bf48f4 0x102bf0000 + 18676 25  libdyld.dylib                    0x0000000182219fc0 start + 4

So I do see some errors but they are all non-specific, not pointing to a specific call.

Can I extract more info from this log or somewhere else to figure out what could have gone wrong?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log, but I see a `doesNotRecogniseSelector` there, which indicates that you have invoked a method on an object that doesn't implement that method.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about 'symbolicate'. That should move me along.